# How to move an old commit to another branch in git?

Tags: git

I do have a project in GIT which currently has 3 branches, `master`, `develop` and `feature/core-md-topbar`.

I was working in the `feature/core-md-topbar` branch and discovered a bug which is present in the `development` branch which I accidentally fixed in the `feature/core-md-topbar` branch.

Now, I don't have anything pushed to the remote yet, but I want my fix to be part of the `develop` branch.

So, this is my current commit:

[image]

So, I want the commit starting with `FIX` and hash `64376b2` to be placed immediately after the second commit with hash `8f928d0`.

Off course, I should not lose any work.

What's the gittish way to solve this problem?

Comment: As a new head/branch out from the history or in between 8f92 and 8b96?

Comment: Does remote have `develop` branch? If yes, which commit is it pointing to?

Comment: If **nothing** of this is pushed you can most likely use an interactive rebase to reorder the changesets.

Comment: Nothing is pushed. You mind sharing the command I require since I've tried alot using rebase and always messed up my repo :-)

Comment: Do you want to apply the fix commit to `development`, reorder commits in `core-md-topbar`, both, or something else?  This is not clear.

Comment: The fix should be applied in `development`. I don't see why commits should be reordered...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cherry-pick the fix commit from `core-md-topbar` to `development`:

```
git checkout development
git cherry-pick 64376b2
```

Remove the fix commit from `core-md-topbar`:

You can try doing an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~8
```

A window looking something like the following should come up.  Note that commits are shown from *oldest* to *newest*.

```
pick 2eb670c comment
pick 8f928d0 comment
pick 8b96886 comment
pick 8fa512e comment
pick 995396f comment
pick dd4ab71 comment
pick 64376b2 comment
pick 704c5da comment
```

**Delete the line** (*DO NOT drop the commit!*) containing the fix commit `64376b2`, leaving you with this:

```
pick 2eb670c comment
pick 8f928d0 comment
pick 8b96886 comment
pick 8fa512e comment
pick 995396f comment
pick dd4ab71 comment
pick 704c5da comment
```

Now save and close the window, which will start the actual rebase.  You may get merge conflicts as each commit is reapplied from 8 commits ago.

The first cherry-pick safe is clean and safe.  But the interactive rebase runs a potential risk if the `core-md-topbar` branch is publicly shared *and* you have published from the fix commit onwards.  If you have published already, then you are much safer to *revert* that fix commit, assuming you don't want in the `core-md-topbar` branch:

```
git checkout core-md-topbar
git revert 64376b2
```

This instructs Git to make a *new* commit on the HEAD of `core-md-topbar` which effectively undoes the fix commit.  And publishing this won't cause problems for a public branch that others are using.

Comment: Is a rebase safe to do when it's spanning multiple branches?

Comment: Wait...I don't understand your requirement.  You made a fix commit in `core-md-topbar` but you want that fix in `development`, but you want to rebase `core-md-topbar`?  This doesn't make any sense.  Please explain.

Comment: The commit must be removed from `core-md-topbar` and applied to `development`.

Comment: This is nothing like what you described.  Give me a few minutes, unless someone else beats me.

Comment: Sorry that my question was not clear. To me, it seems clear :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm just curious what was wrong with the rebase. What was wrong  with the rebase command, you mind explaining?

Comment: You were talking about rearranging commits, etc., which isn't what you wanted.  By your own comments, you want to remove the fix commit from `core-md-topbar` and instead apply it to `development`.

Comment: Bugs don't have to fixed in a way which makes it look like you fixed them right away.  By definition, a bug means that there were some number of commits during which your app had a problem.  All apps have this, it's a fact of life.

Comment: I tweaked your command a bit, because after my interfactive rebase, I still needed to do a rebase to rebase my `feature` branch on my `develop` branch, right? Anyway, I've marked your answer as accepted.

Comment: That sounds OK.  After sorting out the bug fix commit problem, you can rebase feature on development.  This should again bring in the bug fix, but now it is as intended; you fixed a development bug in development, and then brought it into the feature via a rebase.